# What things I need to download apart from android studio to start developing apps?

Tags: android, download, development-environment

I am new to android programming.
I have downloaded and installed Android studio but I am not able to do any work.
Please help me to find out what things at the minimum level I need to download to start developing.
I have slow Internet connection..

Thanks for your advice in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio should be all that you need. Once you start up Android Studio all you have to do is make a new project and start programming. You might need to install build tools but i believe it prompts you to do so when you try to build a project

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl), it's very popular and is used by new developers when they start android development. It explains what all you need to have downloaded to begin with android app development.

You also need to download jdk, and specify the path to it. It will be more clear when you watch his first few videos.

Answer (score 0):

An advice to **any** solution(any), restart the computer after uninstall the program.

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer the question.

Comment: :O Sorry, I confused the topic of the question.